# Is it possible to append page title inside an anchor tag whose href I know using Query?

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor tag in a page:

```
<a href="#cost">Item Cost</a>
```

And the page title is `New York`

I want to append the page title in the anchor tag as:

```
<a href="#cost">Item Cost in New York</a>
```

all anchor tags whose href is `#cost` and inner text is `Item Cost`

I can not edit page in PHP because it is made in Wordpress using a page builder. I can only use jQuery / javascript to edit text on client side.

Can it be done using jQuery?

Comment: You could do something like `$('#cost').text($('#cost').text() + " in " + $(document).find("title").text())` but havent tested

Comment: Why do you want this question to be deleted? Anyway, defacing it is not the proper action. I think you can custom-flag it to ask a moderator to *de-associate* your account from it though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = $('#cost').text() + " in " + document.title;
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>asdasd</title>
<div id='cost'>asdadasd</div>
<a href="#cost">Item Cost</a>
<a href="#cost">Item Cost in New York</a>
```

Note:- You can get the title of document using `document.title` and append it to the text of `$('#cost').text()` div

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.title` and correct jQuery selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // More info https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
    $("a[href|='#cost']").each(function(idx, obj){
        //Your condition
        if($(obj).text() == "Item Cost"){
            $(obj).text($(obj).text() + " in " + document.title);
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>New York</title>
<a href="#cost">Item Cost</a><br/>
<a href="#cost">Item Cost2</a><br/>
...<br/>
<a href="#cost">Item Cost</a><br/>
<a href="#cost">Bad Item Cost</a>
```

Comment: Why the use of `|=` operator? OP didn't talk about matching `href="#cost-foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the `a` elements using the `attribute selector` and also with the `:contains` `jQuery` custom selector : `$('a[href="#cost"]:contains("Item Cost")')` then concatenate the page's title to those elements.

Here's a demo :

```js
$(() => {
  $('a[href="#cost"]:contains("Item Cost")').text('Item Cost ' + $(document).find('title').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>in New York</title>
<a href="#cost">Item Cost</a>
<a href="#cost">Item Cost</a>
```

Comment: Try to change `Item Cost` into `Item Cost2`. It will take it

Comment: @Valijon that's normal due to `:contains` selector.

Comment: But he asks: all anchor tags whose href is #cost and inner text `is` Item Cost

Comment: If `a` text will never have altered text, your solution is more "jQuery" than mine